# mapping superclasses and subclasses with hibernate (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to persist objects in a database using hibernate JPA.

The objects already have a type hierarchy, and I'm trying to make it work with hibernate.

A `CatalogPackage` object has all the important properties and all the getters.
A `CatalogPackageImpl` (`extends CatalogPackage`) object has no properties, but most of the setters.

Both classes are non-abstract.

We want code to refer to `CatalogPackage` objects.  But when initializing hibernate, it complains about the setters missing from the `CatalogPackage` class.

How do I suggest to hibernate that it use the subclass when building the objects?

I don't want to move all the setters to the superclass, and I don't want to use `CatalogPackageImpl` as the entity.

Comment: did you try using `@Access(AccessType.Field)` on superclass? However I don't think that the design you're describing is appropriate - why do you insist on separating getters from setters? It is very likely to cause problems with Hibernate down the road...

Comment: Please update your question by posting your entities

Comment: @Blekit you are right, it did cause problems down the road...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116287/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I can't see the problem with defining the setter methods in your `CatalogPackage` since they can be marked `private` to avoid using them from external world.
Since you didn't paste your entities configuration and that you say Hibernate is complaining about the setter methods I can conclude you are using your getters to describe your entity mapping, right?

In such a case Hibernate will always still complaining because it assumes **anything mapped to the database should be done in both directions**, if it can read from the datastorage so it should be allowed to write in there.

SO you have either of below solutions:

- Add the setters modifiers.
- Move the mapping from getter methods to fields and set the acces type to field on top of your entity:

  ```
  @Access(AccessType.Field)
  class CatalogPackage {
    ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks!  AccessType.FIELD is useful and I've now been playing around with that to achieve what I'm trying to do